# Integrating Doorkeeper and Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery, doorkeeper

I am having trouble with setting up doorkeeper to authenticate using Sorcery..

Sorcery provides a login method via the controller but it doesn't work to use it in the Doorkeeper.rb file.

**Doorkeeper.rb**

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  ...
  resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    login(params[:username], params[:password])
  end
```

Gives this result:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `login' for #<Doorkeeper::TokensController:0x0000000209ee38>):
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to include the sorcery methods within Doorkeeper.

Comment: That makes sense to me, but I'm not sure what to include? For tests there is a test helper that needs to be included, but I'm not sure what needs to be included for the configure blocks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anthonator](https://github.com/anthonator) on github answered my question [here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/pull/415#issuecomment-20740827) but for posterity's sake this is what he said.

This is what I have in initializers/doorkeeper.rb

```
resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
  User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
end
```

I also have this is my API controller

```
private
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
end
```